# problem with jquery and asp.net data exchange

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have a wcf service that i want to call and i know it's returning a JSON string.

**Q1**: how can i find out how the JSON looks like at runtime? for example, if the JSON is {'name':'steive', 'lastname':'jones'} how do i find this parameter names with javascript or jquery?

in the sample jquery like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wcfService.svc/test',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
           // to do
        }
    });
```

**Q2**: how do i know what names data.d contains in the success function??

as you can guess i'm trying to automate the server/client data exchange so if the JSON gets big the client should be able to use the parameters that could be in any names. in the above example i used name and lastname but the client should work with no problem if i change the name to names and lastname to lastnames at server side, like this:
{'names':'steive', 'lastnames':'jones'}
i should be able to use it without any modification to client. i'm using ASP.NET and C#.

**Q3**: is this even possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you sure can!

you can loop through data's properties youse the `for  ... in`  loop.    use `.hasOwnProperty`  to only get the properties that are part of your object and not the base object properties.

```
for (var prop in data ) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        alert(prop + ' '  + data[prop]);
    }
}
```

have a look at this fiddle to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/WNrgs/